# If input has spaces only

Tags: javascript

Hi there everyone how can I detect if the user input has just empty spaces?

**Detect** this:

```
input = ' ';
input = '          ';
etc...
```

**DO NOT** detect this:

```
input 'hi there';
```

I just want to detect if there is a space in the input and that's it?

---

Here is what i have tried:

```
function whitespaceDetect(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}

if(whitespaceDetect(document.getElementById("name").value)) {
    alert('error!');
}
```

but this comes up with an error if the name is "john doe";

What way is the fastest to process? How can i achieve this with or without jquery?

Answer (score 1):

function `trim`

```
str.trim() === ''
```

Comment: I agree with this. It makes more sense than trying to check for "empty spaces". +1